# Usermanager.RemoveFromRoleAsyncIsnotWorkingProperly in .net core 5.0

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-5.0

I am Trying To Remove role For User It Not Work in .net 5.0

```
 var roles = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
 var result = await userManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(user, roles);
```

with both Development and Production server

Answer (score 0):

How do you add user to a role? I give you a workaround example below.

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
    RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager;

    public HomeController(
        UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager,
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager  )
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        roleManager = _roleManager;
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(string username, string password)
    {

        var user = new IdentityUser
        {
            UserName = username,
            Email = "",
        };

        roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("admin"));
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);
        
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var role = _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "admin");
            var roles = _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user).Result;
            
            var resu = await _userManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(user, roles);
            var roles2 = _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user).Result;
            return Redirect("Secret");
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: i have seed role at start time when i am initially add migration in seed data

Comment: Have you added the user to the role? How do you migrate it? Is this value `foles` of `var roles = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);` empty?

Comment: no it works now it actual problem is that I am saving user Using SP so it don't have Value for security, and concurrancystamp that why it not work now i am ok now

Comment: can you try to answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65028094/i-am-not-able-to-access-user-manager-services-from-area-controller-is-that-any-p